# How do I assign the results of a pandas.series.str.contains method in pandas to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following code:

```py
import pandas 

dict1 = {
    "Country" :['USA','France', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'Germany', 'South Africa', 'Portugal', 'Brazil'],
    "Variety" : ['Pinot Gris', 'Pinot Blanc', 'White Blend', 'Sauvignon Blanc', 'Frappato', 'Portuguese Red', 'Red Blend', 'Pinot Noir'],
    "Grade" : [80, 85, 83, 87, 88, 89, 84, 86],
    }

df = pandas.DataFrame(dict1)

df['Type'] = ''
```

What I am trying to do is to go through each row and if a value contains `Red` or `Noir` in the `Variety` column, assign it to a new value called `Red` and append `Red` to that index in the `Type` column.

I used the pandas string contains method but it only returns Boolean values and when I try to loop through it says I can't (of course because they are Boolean values). Does anyone know how to resolve this??

Comment: Please include what the expected output is in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`str.contains` is supposed to return a boolean array. This is because a string will either contain your substring, or it won't. If you want to then overwrite all of those instances where the outputted boolean array is `True` or `False` you'll need to combine `str.contains` with `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np

df["Type"] = np.where(df["Variety"].str.contains(r"Red|Noir"), "Red", "NOT RED")

print(df)
        Country          Variety  Grade     Type
0           USA       Pinot Gris     80  NOT RED
1        France      Pinot Blanc     85  NOT RED
2         Spain      White Blend     83  NOT RED
3         Italy  Sauvignon Blanc     87  NOT RED
4       Germany         Frappato     88  NOT RED
5  South Africa   Portuguese Red     89      Red
6      Portugal        Red Blend     84      Red
7        Brazil       Pinot Noir     86      Red
```

`np.where` takes a boolean array, and assigns values to wherever it is `True` or `False`. In this case I assigned `"Red"` to wherever our boolean array was `True` and `"NOT RED"` wherever the array was `False`.